# Codeigniter - Get several files, rename them and then zip it

Tags: php, codeigniter, zip

I'm making a website, using codeigniter, that will enable users to download files a bit like gmail.  By that I mean that the user can download only 1 file or all files in a zip folder.

Because there will be many files, I have encoded their names to avoid duplicates and stored their original names in a database which returns me an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [file_id] => 2
            [file_name] => v6_copy.pdf
            [file_path] => uploads/4/d5/67697ff58d09d3fb25d563bf85d3f1ac.pdf
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [file_id] => 3
            [file_name] => v4_copy.pdf
            [file_path] => uploads/7/cf/38212079635e93a8f8f4d4a3fc2a11ff.pdf
        )

)
```

**What I need to do is, get each file, rename them to their original names and then zip it in one zip.**  I'm currently trying to use the codeigniter zip helper, but I can't seem to be able to rename the files.

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row) // This returns what you see above
{
    // I need to rename the file somewhere here
    $this->zip->read_file($row->filename); 
}

$this->zip->download('files_backup.zip');
```

Is there a way to do this without creating manually a directory, copying the files, renaming them and then zipping the file?

Any help most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Gordon 's answer, I found a solution.
He is completely right about Codeigniter not being able to rename a file, but I found a really quick change to the library and it seems to be working.

If you go to your system>librairies->Zip.php like mentioned by @Gordon, search for "read_file" and you'll find the function.

Then I simply added a argument to the function and modified some of the code thereafter, see below:

```
function read_file($path, $preserve_filepath = FALSE, $name = NULL) // Added $name
{
    if ( ! file_exists($path))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (FALSE !== ($data = file_get_contents($path)))
    {
            if($name == NULL){  // Added a verification to see if it is set, if not set, then it does it's normal thing, if it is set, it uses the defined var.
        $name = str_replace("\\", "/", $path);

        if ($preserve_filepath === FALSE)
        {
            $name = preg_replace("|.*/(.+)|", "\\1", $name);
        }
            }

        $this->add_data($name, $data);
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

I hope this helps others.  Thanks again @Gordon

Comment: you might want to send a pull request to the git repo. if they accept it, others can use that change, too.

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't be editing the core files (assuming this pull request didn't get added to core), but the same code above could be used to extend the default libraries without editing core files. More information is in the "Extending Native Libraries" section here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: I agree with @KirkBeard here, what if you migrate your code to newer version of codeigniter later? will you remember to change the core file again?

Answer (score 4):

CodeIgniter's Zip Class [apparently](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Zip.php) does not offer any means to rename entries. You can use PHP's native Zip Extension, which allows you to change the name when adding the file to the archive (and also later).

Example from [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-addfile.php)

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('test.zip') === TRUE) {
    $zip->addFile('/path/to/index.txt', 'newname.txt');
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

Comment: Cool, that's interesting.  Thanks for the answer @Gordon.  Does that also store it in a temporary file like Codeigniter?  By that I mean, once it's donwloaded, does it automatically delete?

Comment: @denislexic Not sure tbh. I think it's written to disk.